# Order of items in a category

Tags: php, sql, database-design

I need to make a table to hold data on the order of games in a category. I was planning on just having Game_ID, Category_ID, and Order as the 3 fields, but I'm not sure how to go about the Order field.

I figured I would just have the games with the lowest number in the Order field show up at the top, which would work fine except it could get messy when I want re-order. If I have 50 games and I decide to shuffle a few around, I would have to do a SQL Update on every row in that category to update the order.

Is this the best approach or can it be simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance isn't a concern (and honestly, it usually isn't) then I'd usually just update every item in the set.

If you're trying to optimize perf, you can do some extra logic in the application layer to minimize database updates.  You can have the order field initially populated in increments of 10 (or whatever makes sense).  Then when you re-order an item, in the app layer try to figure out a value for order that would put it in the desired spot.  If not possible then fall back on updating all order values.

I suppose using non-integer order field might make this even more successful, but every time I've seen it implemented was with integer fields.

Comment: There's no reason to use an integer field for an ordering field.  Also, make sure to have a unique index on `(CATEGORY_ID, GAME_ORDER)` - naming a column after a reserved word in every RDBMS seems like a bad idea.